# How to resign shortly after accepting a counter-offer

Tags: resignation, human-resources, counter-offer

I withdrew my resignation 3 weeks back by accepting a counter offer given by current company. I didn't inform the same to the new company yet.
Now again I am thinking to go with the new offer. What shall I say to the HR now so that everything goes smoothly?

Comment: You've messed your employer about badly. It won't go "smoothly". Just try to get out without further damaging your reputation.

Comment: Tank you Philip for your answer. I revoked it by accepting the counter offer and pressure to stay by my company.

Comment: Stop making excuses and start taking responsibility for _your_ actions.

Comment: Has anything material changed in your circumstances (or work environment) that you could use to justify your change of mind? Or was it just a case of second/third thoughts?

Comment: "What shall I say to the HR now so that everything goes smoothly?" - Time for a smooth exit has passed. It's one thing to eventually move on from your position after a period of time, but changing your mind multiple times in single 30 day timeframe, will burn whatever good will you had.

Answer (score 13):

> What shall I say to the HR now so that everything goes smoothly?

No offense but that bridge will be burned if you resign now after accepting their counter offer. There's nothing you can do to smooth things out. Make this a lesson learned and stick to your promises - not just in such a situation but in general, whether it's a written contract or a verbal promise.

Unreliability will reflect badly on you and will ruin your reputation not just within the company but also in the industry if word goes around. That being said - people make mistakes, but shouldn't repeat them a second time.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I havent taken any benefit of counter offer yet. Shall I buy time from new company for joining and inform my current cumpany that I want to go ahead with new company? What you suggest?

Comment: @ArunTP If you plan to go ahaead with the new company, buying time from the company you are about to join could lead to leaving again a bad impression with your new employer  even before you started and won't change anything with your current employer - so at least stick to what you have agreed with the new company. Just hand in your notice, serve your notice period and start with your new employer as agreed.

Comment: “We thought he was here for the love, but it turned out he was only here for the money” said no boss, ever. The employment relationship is mercenary, the employer shouldn’t overdo their “surprise”. If he is actually breaking a contract, that is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you do whatever is in your best interest. Leaving after accepting a counteroffer can be seen as unprofessional and may put you on a "do not rehire" list but you are leaving the company for a reason. Companies let people go with no notice every day for a variety of reasons and you also don't owe your company anything. I would simply explain that you appreciate the counteroffer but after reevaluating your goals and options, you have decided to accept a position with another company. Just be professional and honest. You have no control over whether it goes smoothly or not. They may understand and wish you well or they may pitch a fit and walk you to the door right there but none of that is within your control. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Having accepted the counter offer, I would say you owe the company at least another year before you begin looking for another job again, unless there are truly extreme circumstances.

You had a choice. You made a choice. Presumably it was, at worst, not an unreasonable choice. Stop second-guessing and live with it.

Comment: Nonsense. He doesn't "owe" any company anything and more than the company "owes" him anything. If it was in the company's best interest, they would fire him tomorrow. We can all make mistakes and have the opportunity to rectify that mistake but sometimes it comes with consequences. The consequence of this decision may simply be burning a bridge with the current company but they will get over it.

Comment: Ok, if you prefer, he owes his reputation that year.

Comment: And he owes this to himself to learn caution. Otherwise he's at risk of winding up like the other recent questioner who has had four jobs in four years and is wondering why people don't want to hire him.

Comment: I disagree with this.  You're making a fundamentally wrong assumption that OP can safely keep their job for a year and however long it takes to find a new one.  Unless they're very new to management, OPs bosses know that counter offers very rarely get people to stay more than a short time longer.  Instead they're used to allow the company to find a replacement while still having the person remain on staff.  As soon as that happens OP is no longer a key resource and many companies will take the safest - to them - course of action and fire the person before they can become key personnel again.

Comment: We're cynical about different things, and have had different experiences, apparently. We agree that we disagree.

Comment: @keshlam Yes his reputation with this company is what is at stake and we all owe it to ourselves to protect it zealously. I am not familiar with the other questioner you mention about having 4 jobs in a single year but yes, I would agree with you on that. I was a hiring manager once and would have passed on that candidate (and did many times) but I don't believe this situation has anything to do with that one.

Answer (score -1):

It's as simple as saying: "I've had another think and I've decided to move on".

The best you can really do is be frank about the reasons. If their counter-offer was marginal financially, then say so.

Alternatively, if you're bored or tired in the role, or looking forward to a new challenge, then say so.

I don't agree with others that you owe a certain length of further service.

If you sought to negotiate, lodged a demand, and your demand was met in full, and nothing about the circumstances had changed, then it would be bad form to reopen the matter.

But in the most likely circumstances that the employer made a gratuitous counter-offer which you weren't given very long to consider, that the counter-offer was a bare matching of the new external offer, or that the new external offer had not yet fruited when you accepted the counter-offer, then it seems reasonable that you might ultimately move on anyway.

In general, once someone has invested time and energy in seeking another job, the only way to quench the arc is for the existing employer to match the maximum external offer received or likely to be received, *plus* pay an immediate retention bonus of thousands.

In the past, most employers addressed the matter strategically by ensuring pay always remained competitive, that workforce planning dampened market competition, and that pensions were back-loaded (with "final salary" schemes and similar). But nowadays most employers are just resigned to frequent turnover.